# jQuery find doesn't return single result - SPServices, SharePoint 2010 Search Web Service

Tags: web-services, jquery, spservices, jquery-ui

I'm using SPServices to access the SharePoint Search web service.  When it returns multiple results my code function fine.  However, when it returns on a single result the str.find("Document").length returns 0.

Here's the function:

```
function filterDataWS(){
        var queryText = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>"
        queryText += "<Query>"
        queryText += "<Context>"
        queryText += "<QueryText language='en-US' type='STRING'>"
        queryText += "ContentClass:\"STS_Site\" ContentClass:\"STS_Web\" Title:\"" + $('#webSearch').val().toLowerCase() + "*\"";
        queryText += "</QueryText>"
        queryText += "</Context>"
        queryText += "</Query>"
        queryText += "</QueryPacket>";

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "Query",
            queryXml: queryText,
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                availableTags = new Array();

                $(xData.responseXML).find("QueryResult").each(function() {
                    var x = $("<xml>" + $(this).text() + "</xml>");

                    //let's see what the response looks like
                    //$("#result").text($(this).text());

                    //traverse the xml to get the items
                    x.find("Document").each(function() {
                        url = $("Action>LinkUrl", $(this)).text();
                        //when using keyword syntax
                        title = $("Title", $(this)).text();
                        //end keyword syntax
                        availableTags.push({label: title, value: url});
                    });

                    $("#webSearch").autocomplete({ 
                        source: availableTags, 
                        select: function(value, data){ 
                            $('#goToWeb').attr('href', data.item.value).attr('target', '_blank').css('display', 'inline');
                            $('#webSearch').val(data.item.label);
                            return false;
                        }, 
                        search: function(event, ui){
                            $('#goToWeb').css('display','none');
                        }
                    });

                });
            }
        });

    }
```

Here's a working ResponsePacket XML blob:

```
<ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response">
  <Response>
    <Range>
      <StartAt>1</StartAt>
      <Count>2</Count>
      <TotalAvailable>2</TotalAvailable>
      <Results>
        <Document relevance="100000000" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document">
          <Title>FBI</Title>
          <Action>
            <LinkUrl size="102147">http://sp2010/FBI</LinkUrl>
          </Action>
          <Description />
          <Date>2012-10-18T14:33:11</Date>
        </Document>
        <Document relevance="100000000" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document">
          <Title>FEMA</Title>
          <Action>
            <LinkUrl size="102249">http://sp2010/FEMA</LinkUrl>
          </Action>
          <Description />
          <Date>2012-10-18T14:33:11</Date>
        </Document>
      </Results>
    </Range>
    <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
  </Response>
</ResponsePacket>
```

Here's the full response XML.  The QueryResult has an encoded value.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <QueryResponse xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
      <QueryResult>&lt;ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response"&gt;&lt;Response&gt;&lt;Range&gt;&lt;StartAt&gt;1&lt;/StartAt&gt;&lt;Count&gt;1&lt;/Count&gt;&lt;TotalAvailable&gt;1&lt;/TotalAvailable&gt;&lt;Results&gt;&lt;Document relevance="100000000" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"&gt;&lt;Title&gt;FBI&lt;/Title&gt;&lt;Action&gt;&lt;LinkUrl size="102147"&gt;http://sp2010/FBI&lt;/LinkUrl&gt;&lt;/Action&gt;&lt;Description /&gt;&lt;Date&gt;2012-10-18T14:33:11&lt;/Date&gt;&lt;/Document&gt;&lt;/Results&gt;&lt;/Range&gt;&lt;Status&gt;SUCCESS&lt;/Status&gt;&lt;/Response&gt;&lt;/ResponsePacket&gt;</QueryResult>
    </QueryResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If you remove one of the Document elements, it returns a length of 0.

Any idea of how to resolve this?

Comment: Didn't work for me. x.find("Document").each... still returns no rows. Any other suggestions? xData.responseXML is fully populated with documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's parseXML solved the issue.  It now works in IE9, Chrome, and FireFox.  Here's what it looks like:

```
$().SPServices({
            operation: "Query",
            queryXml: queryText,
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                availableTags = new Array();

                $(xData.responseXML).find("QueryResult").each(function() {
                    var x = "<xml>" + $(this).text() + "</xml>";
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(x);
                    x = $(xmlDoc);

                        //traverse the xml to get the items
                        x.find("Document").each(function() {
                            url = $("Action>LinkUrl", $(this)).text();
                            //when using keyword syntax
                            title = $("Title", $(this)).text();
                            //end keyword syntax
                            availableTags.push({label: title, value: url});
                        });
                });

                $("#webSearch").autocomplete({ 
                        source: availableTags, 
                        select: function(value, data){ 
                            $('#goToWeb').attr('href', data.item.value).attr('target', '_blank').css('display', 'inline');
                            $('#webSearch').val(data.item.label);
                            return false;
                        }, 
                        search: function(event, ui){
                            $('#goToWeb').css('display','none');
                        }
                });
            }
        });
```